# I downloaded XAMPP and when I try to open local files it tells me it cant be found on the server

Tags: php, xampp

I started watching thenewboston's tutorial on php, and when I try to save a file to htdocs and run it on my local server, it tells me it cant be found. How would I connect to my local server? I have tried several times now so I'm sure I didn't have any spelling errors and I also have apache and mysql running. I have tried searching google but I couldn't find anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to access any files at all on the server? phpmyadmin, php.ini etc?

Comment: How are you trying to access the server? What OS are you using?

Comment: Have you enabled the services provided by XAMPP ?

Comment: check for hidden files do you have .htaccess in htdocs folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions:

1. Check `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in your browser
2. Make sure the ending url is exactly the same as the file name.
3. If everything is running check `localhost/phpmyadmin`

Comment: Ya I can access localhost and phpmyadmin, but when I try to create my own file and open it up, it tells me it cant be found on the server.

Comment: Could be file permissions or as someone mentioned above make sure you have no hidden `.htaccess` files.